# Hello Analytics Reporting API v4; JavaScript quickstart for web applications

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to make a functional connection to GA API according to the official docs - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js. I did everything needed to set it up however the solution is not working. The weird thing is that the button for the authentication is loaded and its working up until the point where I select the google account to login with. After that however loading appears and the auth window gets closed. There is no error in the console, nothing happens at all.

I use it on localhost currently but I've also tried it on a server with the same result. After selecting the account, every next attempt doesn't even require choosing the account so the window just opens, loading appears and closes again without anything happening.[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOTQN.png)
[Credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akYXB.png)                                       [Google_Analytics_View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldCEC.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello Analytics Reporting API V4</title>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="1086039826600-2r3481ge270o57vau3kshic6l4vrg4gg.apps.googleusercontent.com">
  <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello Analytics Reporting API V4</h1>

<!-- The Sign-in button. This will run `queryReports()` on success. -->
<p class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="queryReports"></p>

<!-- The API response will be printed here. -->
<textarea cols="80" rows="20" id="query-output"></textarea>

<script>
  // Replace with your view ID.
  var VIEW_ID = '271208943';

  // Query the API and print the results to the page.
  function queryReports() {
    gapi.client.request({
      path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
      root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        reportRequests: [
          {
            viewId: VIEW_ID,
            dateRanges: [
              {
                startDate: '7daysAgo',
                endDate: 'today'
              }
            ],
            metrics: [
              {
                expression: 'ga:sessions'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
  }

  function displayResults(response) {
    var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;
  }
</script>

<!-- Load the JavaScript API client and Sign-in library. -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue you are having is that that sample is using [Google Sign-In for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)

> We are discontinuing the Google Sign-In JavaScript Platform Library for web. The library will be unavailable for download after the March 31, 2023 deprecation date. Instead, use the new Google Identity Services for Web.
> By default, newly created Client IDs are now blocked from using the older Platform Library, existing Client IDs are unaffected. New Client IDs created before July 29th, 2022 can set `plugin_name` to enable use of the Google Platform Library.

Which means it doesn't work any more.   I will ping the team, but last I heard they were still working on updating all of the Javascript samples.

Seeing as UA analytics is going to be discontinued in January I question wither or not they will even bother updating the samples for this api.

I will get back to you when i hear anything

Comment: Thank you for the respond and help, I also found a lot of problem while using UA since it'll be replaced very soon, but for the sample code that can fetch data form Google Analytics I only found a version that work for UA which required a ViewID (GA4 don't have a view ID), do you eventually have any idea is there any sample code that google provide can fetch data form GA4 to customized html dash board

Comment: you need to use the google analytics data api to extract data from ga4

Comment: I am so appreciate for your help and kindness!!! But I actually also met problem while using Google Analytics Data Api on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73029058/question-concerning-google-analytics-data-api

Answer (score 0):

So after the suspection that Google Sign-In is not in used anymore, I follow the instruction of migration to Google Identity Services and I add this line  ****meta name="google-signin-plugin_name" content="quickstart"****  but I still didn't get the data properly loaded or sign-in[image]I am not sure if the plugin-name is the "quickstart" as in the second screenshot[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello Analytics Reporting API V4</title>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="1086039826600-2r3481ge270o57vau3kshic6l4vrg4gg.apps.googleusercontent.com">
  <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly">
  <meta name="google-signin-plugin_name" content="quickstart">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello Analytics Reporting API V4</h1>

<!-- The Sign-in button. This will run `queryReports()` on success. -->
<p class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="queryReports"></p>

<!-- The API response will be printed here. -->
<textarea cols="80" rows="20" id="query-output"></textarea>

<script>
  // Replace with your view ID.
  var VIEW_ID = '271208943';

  // Query the API and print the results to the page.
  function queryReports() {
    gapi.client.request({
      path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
      root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
      method: 'POST',
      
      body: {
        reportRequests: [
          {
            viewId: VIEW_ID,
            dateRanges: [
              {
                startDate: '7daysAgo',
                endDate: 'today'
              }
            ],
            metrics: [
              {
                expression: 'ga:sessions'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
  }

  function displayResults(response) {
    var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;
  }
</script>

<!-- Load the JavaScript API client and Sign-in library. -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```